# Is it possible to install and work with Hyperledger explorer from Fabric client node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

Is it possible to install fabric client node ? 
I am working with Aamzon managed block chain and I don`t see a way to use or have ready Hyperledger explorer on AWS managed block chain. Is it possible to have the endpoint for the same on this netwrok and how ? I have seen people using AWS hyperledger blockchain templates to generate the endpoint but not in the managed version. 
If it is not possible, is it possible to install and use the same on the fabric client node and not on network ?

Priority would be to generate hyperledger explorer endpoint on AWS managed blockchain network if this is not possible how to do it on fabric client node or is it ok or possible to do so ? 
Any ideas or suggestions are welcome !